# One Word for Shocking and Aggressive

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What is a word for shocking and aggressive? Like, "He looks shockingly, aggressively muscular." A similar thought I'm trying to describe may be something which is stunning and predatory. Additionally, I the particular connotation I feel is positive, or at least a kind of admiration for the thing/person who is shocking and aggressive.

Comment: I think this question is still a bit vague. Can you give an example sentence with a blank space where you would use this word? It would also be good if you went through the [question checklist for single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and added as much of that information as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for **"threatening"**, **"menacing"**, **"intimidating"** or **"thuggish looking"**

> - **a thuggish-looking stranger**
> - **an intimidating behavior**
> - **a menacing posture**

Comment: I thinking menacing is closest, but had both a negative premise and a slow, glooming progression of an unspoken threat. However, the particular connotation I'm going for is positive or admirable. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

How about **audacious**?

> adjective
>
> 1. extremely bold or daring; recklessly brave; fearless: *an audacious explorer.*
> 2. extremely original; without restriction to prior ideas; highly inventive: *an audacious vision of the city's bright future.*
> 3. recklessly bold in defiance of convention, propriety, law, or the like; insolent; brazen.
> 4. lively; unrestrained; uninhibited: *an audacious interpretation of her role.*
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/audacious?s=t))